# Docking CDialogBar Horizontally with CToolbar

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I need to display a CToolbar (m_wndToolBar) and a CDialogBar (m_wndDlgBarSid1) horizontally (i.e. next to each other, not above one another).  The parent frame is derived from CMDIFrameWnd.

I've tried all sorts of variations to get this to work.  While I can properly position the CDialogBar to the right of the CToolbar, I cannot persist the positioning, although the WINDOWPLACEMENT mechanism is working correctly (the registry is written on program exit); whenever the program is run, the CToolbar shows up docked left, and the CDialogBar shows up below it, also docked left.  I'm using (perforce) MFC and Visual C++ 6.0.  Here's the code, slightly redacted to remove debug printouts and the like:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
   if (CMDIFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
   {
      return -1;
   }
   if (!m_wndToolBar.Create(this) || !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME) )
   {
      return -1;      // fail to create
   }
   if (!m_wndDlgBarSid1.Create(this, IDD_DIALOGBAR_SID1, CBRS_ALIGN_TOP, AFX_IDW_DIALOGBAR))
   {
      return -1;        // fail to create
   }

   WINDOWPLACEMENT wp ;
   CString sSection = "DialogBarSettings";
   CString sEntry = "Sid1";
   if ( ReadWindowPlacement( &wp, sSection, sEntry ))
   {
      BOOL bSWP = m_wndDlgBarSid1.SetWindowPlacement( &wp );
      RecalcLayout();
   }

   m_wndToolBar.SetBarStyle(m_wndToolBar.GetBarStyle() | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC);
   m_wndToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().ModifyStyle( 0, TBSTYLE_FLAT, 0 ) ;
   m_wndDlgBarSid1.SetBarStyle(m_wndToolBar.GetBarStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY ) ;

   m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
   EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
   DockControlBar(&m_wndToolBar);

   m_wndDlgBarSid1.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_TOP | CBRS_ALIGN_BOTTOM);
   DockControlBar(&m_wndDlgBarSid1,AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_TOP);

   return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Arrrg...I apologize for the formatting; the interface implied that it would be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this below code before returning zero. This will load the previously saved docking state.

```
CDockState dockState;
dockState.LoadState(L"CTRLBARSDOCKSTATE.INI");
SetDockState(dockState);
RecalcLayout();
```

To save the current docking state when the window is closed, paste the below code in the CMainFrame::OnClose() override.

```
CDockState dockState;
GetDockState(dockState);
dockState.SaveState(L"CTRLBARSDOCKSTATE.INI");//File name can be of your choice
```

Answer (score 0):

Wound up using CReBar, which comes pretty close to what I need.